# Select single row to two row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
ID     Type       Category      Description

20     Space      Board Type    Painted Bulletin Revenue
21     Space      Board Type    8-Sheet Billboard Revenue
22     Space      Board Type    Short Term Revenue
```

This is the table that I have, since description can be huge I want to have my select on the format below, it is for populating grid and can be done on front end but if its on sql it good

```
ID                             Type       Category   

20                             Space      Board Type    
Painted Bulletin Revenue
21                             Space      Board Type    
8-Sheet Billboard Revenue
22                             Space      Board Type    
Short Term Revenue
```

Comment: Yes it's possible to do in SQL, but I'm 100% that you should not do it in SQL. It's obviously a front-end task. Use SQL to store and get data and use front-end to format this data as you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT [ID], [Type], [Category] FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS SNo,CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),[ID]) AS ID , [Type], [Category],ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ID]) rnk FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS SNo,[Description]  AS ID,'' AS [Type],'' AS [Category],ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ID]) rnk FROM Table1
) t
ORDER BY rnk,SNo
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6b17/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
ID                      Type    Category
20                      Space   Board Type
Painted Bulletin Revenue        
21                      Space   Board Type
8-Sheet Billboard Revenue       
22                      Space   Board Type
Short Term Revenue
```